# Zoom client resets webcam settings

Tags: webcam, logitech, zoom-meeting

I have setup my webcam (Logitech C920) via v4l2:

```
 v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video5 \ 
 --set-ctrl=gain=10 \
 --set-ctrl=power_line_frequency=1 \
 --set-ctrl=backlight_compensation=1 \
 --set-ctrl=exposure_auto=1 \
 --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=300 \
 --set-ctrl=exposure_auto_priority=1
```

It's doing fine with cheese (or similar).

However: Everytime I use the Zoom client (v5.5.7938.0228 from zoom.us) - even when I join different meeting rooms - all settings are reset to the default values and I need to execute above code again and again...

**=> How can I prevent zoom client from resetting my webcam settings (or how can i autoreload them automatically)=**